# WebHID API: How do I parse data from inputReport event?

Tags: javascript, usb-hid, webhid

I'm trying to grab sensor input from my digitizer ( X Tilt, Y Tilt, Tip Pressure, Tip Switch, Eraser, Pen, Puck .etc) using the WebHID API. This is what I've gotten so far:

**index.js:**

```js
page_log = text => {
  let p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = text;
  log.appendChild(p);
};

let device;

if (!("hid" in navigator)) {
  page_log("WebHID is not available yet.");
}

navigator.hid.getDevices().then(devices => {
  if (devices.length == 0) {
    page_log(`No HID devices selected. Press the "request device" button.`);
    return;
  }
  if (devices.length > 1) {
    page_log(`You have multiple devices.`);
  }
  device = devices[0];
  page_log(`User previously selected "${device.productName}" HID device.`);
  page_log(`Now press "open device" button to receive input reports.`);
});

requestDeviceButton.onclick = async event => {
  document.body.style.display = "none";
  try {
    const filters = [
      {
        vendorId: 0x056a, // Wacom Co., Ltd
        productId: 0x00b1 //PTZ-630 [Intuos3 (6x8)]
      },
      {
        vendorId: 0x056a, // Wacom Co., Ltd
        productId: 0x00b2 //PTZ-930 [Intuos3 (9x12)]
      },
      {
        vendorId: 0x056a, // Wacom Co., Ltd
        productId: 0x00b3 //PTZ-1230 [Intuos3 (12x12)]
      },
      {
        vendorId: 0x056a, // Wacom Co., Ltd
        productId: 0x00b4 //PTZ-1231W [Intuos3 (12x19)]
      },
    ];

    [device] = await navigator.hid.requestDevice({ filters });
    if (!device) return;

    page_log(`User selected "${device.productName}" HID device.`);
    page_log(`Now press "open device" button to receive input reports.`);
  } finally {
    document.body.style.display = "";
  }
};


openButton.onclick = async event => {
  if (!device) return;

  await device.open().catch(console.error);
  page_log(`Waiting for user to press button...`);

  device.addEventListener("inputreport", event => {
    const { data, device, reportId } = event;

    let buffArray = new Uint8Array(data.buffer);
    console.log(buffArray);
    // console.log(device);
  
  });
};
```

**console output:**

```
index.js:72 Uint8Array(9) [224, 49, 125, 58, 74, 0, 35, 195, 85]
index.js:72 Uint8Array(9) [224, 49, 109, 58, 64, 0, 35, 194, 94]
index.js:72 Uint8Array(9) [224, 49, 94, 58, 43, 0, 35, 194, 102]
index.js:72 Uint8Array(9) [224, 49, 82, 58, 22, 0, 35, 193, 113]
index.js:72 Uint8Array(9) [224, 49, 52, 58, 1, 0, 35, 193, 123]
index.js:72 Uint8Array(9) [224, 49, 26, 57, 228, 0, 35, 192, 128]
index.js:72 Uint8Array(9) [224, 48, 253, 57, 190, 0, 35, 64, 141]
index.js:72 Uint8Array(9) [224, 48, 223, 57, 137, 0, 35, 65, 148]
index.js:72 Uint8Array(9) [224, 48, 203, 57, 90, 0, 35, 66, 159]
index.js:72 Uint8Array(9) [224, 48, 186, 57, 36, 0, 35, 66, 167]
index.js:72 Uint8Array(9) [224, 48, 177, 56, 242, 0, 35, 67, 174]
index.js:72 Uint8Array(9) [224, 48, 166, 56, 208, 0, 35, 196, 178]
```

How do I find out which sensor each number corresponds to?

I've tried reading [WebHID spec](https://wicg.github.io/webhid/) and [HID Usage Tables](https://usb.org/document-library/hid-usage-tables-122) but I've so far been unable to locate the information I need to decipher the output.

---

### Update:

I've tested in Windows after installing Wacom's official driver I get more data from the InputReport.

**output: (Windows w/ wacom driver)**

```
index.js:73 reportId: 15
index.js:76 Uint8Array(10) [2, 224, 55, 229, 45, 137, 0, 30, 176, 195]
index.js:73 reportId: 15
index.js:76 Uint8Array(21) [2, 224, 55, 163, 45, 99, 0, 31, 49, 189, 15, 2, 224, 55, 98, 45, 69, 0, 31, 49, 190]
index.js:73 reportId: 7
index.js:76 Uint8Array(37) [32, 29, 90, 238, 97, 50, 3, 0, 0, 34, 8, 16, 0, 87, 126, 112, 8, 34, 8, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 212, 254, 192, 249, 232, 28, 184, 136, 0, 0]
index.js:73 reportId: 7
index.js:76 Uint8Array(37) [32, 241, 89, 197, 97, 30, 3, 0, 0, 34, 8, 16, 0, 87, 126, 112, 8, 34, 8, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 56, 255, 36, 250, 76, 29, 228, 137, 0, 0]
index.js:73 reportId: 7
index.js:76 Uint8Array(37) [32, 162, 89, 144, 97, 30, 3, 0, 0, 34, 8, 16, 0, 87, 126, 112, 8, 34, 8, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 56, 255, 36, 250, 76, 29, 228, 137, 0, 0]
index.js:73 reportId: 7
index.js:76 Uint8Array(37) [32, 136, 89, 123, 97, 22, 3, 0, 0, 34, 8, 16, 0, 87, 126, 112, 8, 34, 8, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 56, 255, 36, 250, 76, 29, 228, 137, 0, 0]
index.js:73 reportId: 15
index.js:76 Uint8Array(10) [2, 224, 55, 34, 45, 31, 0, 31, 178, 185]
index.js:73 reportId: 15
index.js:76 Uint8Array(32) [2, 224, 54, 215, 45, 2, 0, 32, 50, 183, 15, 2, 224, 54, 139, 44, 226, 0, 32, 179, 183, 15, 2, 224, 54, 62, 44, 187, 0, 33, 52, 178]
index.js:73 reportId: 7
index.js:76 Uint8Array(37) [32, 27, 89, 51, 97, 14, 3, 0, 0, 34, 8, 16, 0, 87, 126, 112, 8, 34, 8, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 156, 255, 136, 250, 176, 29, 16, 139, 0, 0]
index.js:73 reportId: 7
index.js:76 Uint8Array(37) [32, 171, 88, 237, 96, 6, 3, 0, 0, 34, 8, 16, 0, 87, 126, 112, 8, 34, 8, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 136, 250, 176, 29, 0, 0, 0, 0]
index.js:73 reportId: 7
index.js:76 Uint8Array(37) [32, 53, 88, 163, 96, 254, 2, 0, 0, 34, 8, 16, 0, 87, 126, 112, 8, 34, 8, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 236, 250, 20, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0]
index.js:73 reportId: 15
index.js:76 Uint8Array(10) [2, 224, 53, 239, 44, 147, 0, 34, 54, 175]
```

*Note: I've logged the `reportId` this time because I'm now getting 2 different ones.*

I'm also noticing different data in the `HIDDevice.collections` object:
[image: devtools screenshot windows]
This time I'm getting something in one of my `outputReports`.

**output: (Linux for comparison)**

```
index.js:73 reportId: 2
index.js:74 Uint8Array(9) [224, 31, 174, 22, 67, 0, 38, 203, 177]
index.js:73 reportId: 2
index.js:74 Uint8Array(9) [224, 31, 33, 21, 8, 0, 39, 204, 180]
index.js:73 reportId: 2
index.js:74 Uint8Array(9) [224, 30, 165, 20, 8, 0, 40, 77, 183]
index.js:73 reportId: 2
index.js:74 Uint8Array(9) [224, 30, 16, 19, 51, 0, 40, 206, 182]
index.js:73 reportId: 2
index.js:74 Uint8Array(9) [224, 29, 134, 18, 97, 0, 41, 80, 181]
index.js:73 reportId: 2
index.js:74 Uint8Array(9) [224, 29, 9, 17, 191, 0, 39, 80, 183]
index.js:73 reportId: 2
index.js:74 Uint8Array(9) [224, 28, 210, 17, 27, 0, 36, 215, 184]
index.js:73 reportId: 2
index.js:74 Uint8Array(9) [224, 28, 225, 16, 150, 0, 35, 86, 186]
index.js:73 reportId: 2
index.js:74 Uint8Array(9) [224, 29, 45, 16, 15, 0, 33, 83, 184]
index.js:73 reportId: 2
index.js:74 Uint8Array(9) [224, 29, 162, 15, 153, 0, 32, 83, 190]
index.js:73 reportId: 2
index.js:74 Uint8Array(9) [224, 30, 110, 15, 51, 0, 32, 86, 195]
index.js:73 reportId: 2
index.js:74 Uint8Array(9) [224, 31, 96, 14, 214, 0, 31, 87, 199]
index.js:73 reportId: 2
index.js:74 Uint8Array(9) [160, 32, 212, 14, 142, 0, 26, 216, 202]
```

Also the `HIDDevice.collections` I get on linux:
[image]

So I still don't understand how to map the data using either the `featureReports`, `InputReports` or `OutputReports`. So all I've figured out I get more HID data from Wacom's driver on Windows than linux.

---

### Update 2:

I have been looking at the `HIDDevice.collection` Object on the Windows output and comparing it to `Report Descriptors` I get from running `usbhid-dump` with `hidrd-convert` (for making them human readable) on Linux. This is what I've found out so far.

- It looks like all I need to look at is the `inputReports` element with the appropriate `reportID` as I'm only trying to read the sensor data being sent to the host.
- I look at the array of `items` to see what data being sent by the report.

  - I look at the index number of the item in `items` to know the order to extract the data from the DataView (my `data` variable).
  - I look at `reportCount` and `reportSize` to know the shape of the data for that item in the DataView.
  - I look at the *"Usage"* each item to know what the data is for.

    - Unfortunately WebHID doesn't seem to expose *"Usage"* on a per item bases (Like my *"Report Descriptors"* from `usbhid-dump` shows). Instead it only exposes it on a per collection basis.
    - The "Usage" (if it was available) could be looked up in the [HID Usage Tables](https://usb.org/document-library/hid-usage-tables-122) by looking up the "Usage Page" by the hex value of `usagePage` for the `collection`, then doing the same for the given `usage` hex value.

**Example:**

```js
    if (reportId !== 7) return;
    console.log('reportId: ' + reportId);
    let zero_through_six = data.getUint8(0);


    let report_data = [
      (zero_through_six & 128) == 128,  //0 (1-bit)
      (zero_through_six & 64) == 64,    //1 (1-bit)
      (zero_through_six & 32) == 32,    //2 (1-bit)
      (zero_through_six & 16) == 16,    //3 (1-bit)
      (zero_through_six & 8) == 8,      //4 (1-bit)
      (zero_through_six & 4) == 4,      //5 (1-bit)
      zero_through_six & 3,             //6 (2-bits)
      data.getUint16(1), //7
      data.getUint16(3), //8
      data.getUint16(5), //9
      data.getUint16(7), //10
      data.getUint32(9), //11
      data.getBigUint64(13), //12
      data.getUint32(21), //13
      data.getUint16(23), //14
      data.getUint16(25), //15
      data.getUint16(27), //16
      data.getUint16(29), //17
      data.getUint16(31), //18
      data.getUint16(33), //19
    ];

    console.log(report_data);

  });
```

This is something I did on the to split the data I was getting into and array on the Windows version. The first *items[1-6]* were 1-bit, *items[7]* 2-bits, *items[7-10]* 16-bits and so on.

Again, because WebHID doesn't expose *"Usage"* on a per item basis, the sensor/button each item is mapped to is still unknown. At least outside of simple testing each one individually, which is hard to do on such a complex device.

### Update 3:

Turns out that I don't really need the `WebHID API` for my use case (getting sensor input from my digitizer). Looks like `PointerEvent` and `MouseEvent` properties cover my needs. *(Really, should've look at that first actually (；一_一))* Atleast, I learned somewhat how to use the WebHID API.

Answer (score 2):

I guess https://web.dev/devices-introduction/ would have been useful as it explains how to pick the appropriate API to communicate with a hardware device of your choice.

Glad you figured it out!